# Unable to get comments of particular facebook post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to hit facebook's graph API and retrieve comments of a particular posts but only getting the following error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unknown path components: /100281786832302_492601577600319/comments",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500,
      "fbtrace_id": "BDWKx9eAXzZ"
   }
}
```

Trying to hit below link-

https://graph.facebook.com/AmazonIN/100281786832302_492601577600319/comments?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxx

Does facebook as revoked the access to comments like this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys I got my error it was the url I was hitting I need to remove the page name.

`Don't`
https://graph.facebook.com/AmazonIN/100281786832302_492601577600319/comments?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxx

`DO:`
https://graph.facebook.com/100281786832302_492601577600319/comments?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxx

**Removed the page name AmazonIN**